# How can I click on buttons with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, button

I want to click on "Show more" under the description of this [listing](https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/50293998?adults=1&children=0&infants=0&check_in=2022-06-21&check_out=2022-06-28&federated_search_id=9f8562f3-653a-45b7-b6bd-218379131b41&source_impression_id=p3_1653519105_nsyk%2Fkxp2MNH1yam) by using selenium (I am trying to collect data of multiple listings).

[This is what the HTML looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWr7C.png)

```
<button type="button" class="b1k5q1b3 v19vkvko dir dir-ltr">...</button>
```

I have tried using By.CLASS_NAME method but I get an error saying unable to locate element:

```
url = "https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/50293998?adults=1&children=0&infants=0&check_in=2022-06-21&check_out=2022-06-28&federated_search_id=9f8562f3-653a-45b7-b6bd-218379131b41&source_impression_id=p3_1653519105_nsyk%2Fkxp2MNH1yam"

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver_path = "C:/Users/parkj/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = Service(driver_path))
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "b1k5q1b3 v19vkvko dir dir-ltr")
button.click()
```

[This is what the error looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWfOA.png)

Answer (score 0):

`driver.find_element(By.ID "<ID>").click()` is one example of finding an element, and then clicking it. We could alternatively try something like

```
Questions = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "-link--channel-name")
Questions.click()
```